# AWS lambda- upgrade packages

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, gitlab, gitlab-ci

As per AWS, they are removing botocore from the python lambda environments(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/)

They say we need to run pip install requests from the terminal window before using it. How we can run "pip3 install " whenever we deploy our cloud infrastructure using Gitlab CI/CD pipeline to AWS? Anyone has got any ideas?

Here is the sample pipeline

```
zip-creation:
  image: "python:3.7"
  stage: package
  before_script:
    - apt update
    - apt install zip -y
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - cd scripts/app-infra/
    - zip -r puloski-services-log-error.zip puloski-services-log-error.py
    - zip -r puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.zip puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.py
    - zip -r puloski-s3.zip puloski-s3.py cfnresponse.py
    - zip -r puloski-infra.zip *.yml *.json puloski-ssm-param-versions.sh puloski-services-log-error.zip puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.zip puloski-s3.zip -x buildspec.yml gitlab-ci.yml *.py yamllint-rules
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - scripts/app-infra/buildspec.zip
      - scripts/app-infra/puloski-infra.zip
    expire_in: 3 day
```

Comment: Please provide your sample pipeline. Make sure you obfuscate account number and credentials, if any.

Comment: I edited my question and added part of the pipeline

Comment: thanks for the details, I have added answer that would solve your problem hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your pipeline to include the packages needed by your Lambda function as:

```
script:
    - cd scripts/app-infra/ && mkdir packages && cd packages
    - pip install requests -t . #or python3 -m pip install requests -t .
    - cd ..
    #Making zip with respective files only. Including requests package for all zip files in this example.
    #Package1
    - cp puloski-services-log-error.py packages/
    - zip -r puloski-services-log-error.zip packages/*
    - rm packages/puloski-services-log-error.py
    #Package2
    - cp puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.py packages/
    - zip -r puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.zip packages/*
    - rm packages/puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.py
    #Package3
    - cp {puloski-s3.py,cfnresponse.py} packages/
    - zip -r puloski-s3.zip packages/*
    - rm packages/puloski-s3.py packages/cfnresponse.py
    - zip -r puloski-infra.zip *.yml *.json puloski-ssm-param-versions.sh puloski-services-log-error.zip puloski-subscription-filter-custom-resource.zip puloski-s3.zip -x buildspec.yml gitlab-ci.yml *.py yamllint-rules packages
```

Here you can observe that we have installed request package in a specific directory and made zip files while including that package and its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Building Python Lambdas can be a bit tricky in CI/CD, because "cross-compiling" is not yet a big thing in the Python world (I think `wheels` are supposed to fix this).

Cross-compiling means "building" a (Python) program on one operating system that can run on another operating system and/or architecture.

Simple Python dependencies should not be a problem, because they don't require any operating system specific dependencies. But a few image processing things and other dependencies need binaries that are compiled for specific operating systems and architectures.

The first thing to know is that AWS Lambda is using the `amd64` architecture and a Linux kernel.

So if you want to be sure that your dependencies are running properly in a Lambda, you need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on a system with a Linux kernel and `amd64` architecture.

Fortunately, there is a project that helps you here called LambCI. They have [pre-build Docker images](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) for this exact use case, so you don't need to bother building them.

A very simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` example could look like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

package layer:
  stage: build 
  image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/libs/python"
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/libs
    - zip --recurse-paths layer.zip .
```

This would be downloading all the dependencies you defined in your `requirements.txt` in a directory called `libs/python` in your build pipelines working directory. Don't mind this will be in your pipelines jobs working directory. It won't be committed to your repo. After the job ends, this will be gone again. After the download it will `zip` all the downloaded files into a ZIP archive called `layer.zip`. This is what you need to use as a Lambda Layer and deploy to AWS. Since you did not say which deployment tool you are using (`aws-cli`, Terraform, CDK, etc.), I can't tell how to proceed once you have the zip.

One important thing to note: [the dependencies need to be in a specific directory in the Lambda ZIP archive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path). For Python this is either `python/` or `python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`. That's why the above "code" downloads the requirements to `libs/python` and then archives the `python` directory "into" the tip archive.

Personal note: We are running a lot of Lambdas and personally, if it is not a Lambda@Edge (where you only can use NodeJS or Python) or something that absolutely requires Python (some ML stuff), I would strongly recommend to use something easier to build and compile, like [Go](https://golang.org). It can be quite cumbersome to get Python Lambdas to work.

For example: you can build a Go binary on any operating system to run on an AWS Lambda like so:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Then just zip the resulting binary and deploy it and you are done.